# Using Torah as a punishment

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, reward-punishment, yeshiva-school, psychology

I remember hearing or seeing somewhere that a Rebbi who uses the Torah for a punsihment can make a student hate Torah.  For example,a boy speaks in class ,then the Rebbi makes the boy write over a whole perek of chumash. The boy will come to hate the Torah. They held never give a student a punsihment which involves Torah. Which gadol (gedolim) said this idea?

Comment: Don't know if anyone says it, but it's pretty much common sense...

Comment: obviously not since almost every Rabbi in my youth thrived on this concept ...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. They clearly didn't have much of a grasp of human psychology if they thought punishing you with something would endear you to it... Maybe they were hoping for stockholm syndrome?

Comment: I went to very classic yeshivas and my rebbiem were old school (some even European ) could be thats what they were used to.